Log Analytics workspace does not see existing data rules via terraform
I have problem with data rule. I create terraform code that create Log Analytics workspace and data rule and diag settings and all is fine all create butt when i want to create transformation it did not see existing data rule. Someone can help me or maybe now how to fix? I use azurerm version = “~>3.103.1”
This is my code
`
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "backenddiagnosticsettings" {
  name               = "${var.resource_group_prefix}-${var.application_environment_name}-be${var.instance_name}-logs"
  target_resource_id = azurerm_linux_web_app.backend.id[enter image description here]
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.logworkspace.id # data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.logworkspace.id
  enabled_log {
    category = "AppServiceConsoleLogs"

    retention_policy {
      enabled = true
    }
  }

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"

    retention_policy {
      enabled = true
    }
  }
}





data "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "example" {
  name                = "example-rule"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

output "rule_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "logworkspace" {
  name                = "${var.resource_group_prefix}-${var.application_environment_name}${var.instance_name}-logs"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.apprg.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
  data_collection_rule_id = ["${azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule.backendlogs-dcr.id}"]
  
}




resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "backendlogs-dcr" {
  name                = "${var.resource_group_prefix}-${var.application_environment_name}-backend-dcr"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.apprg.name
  location            = var.location
 
  
  destinations {
    log_analytics {
      name = "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.logworkspace.name}"
      workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.logworkspace.id
    }
  }
  

  data_flow {
    streams       = ["Microsoft-Table-AppServiceConsoleLogs"]
    #destinations  = ["example-destination-log"]
    destinations = ["${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.logworkspace.name}"]
    output_stream = "Microsoft-AppServiceConsoleLogs"
    transform_kql = "source\n| extend Context = parse_json(ResultDescription)\n| extend Thread_CF = tostring(Context.thread)\n| extend Level_CF = tostring(Context.level)\n| extend Logger_CF = tostring(Context.logger)\n| extend Message_CF = tostring(Context.message)\n| project-away Context,ResultDescription" 
    #"source\n| extend LL_CF = substring(ResultDescription, 12, 34)"
  }


  

}



enter image description here
To help with this error

Try using depends on meta argument as provisioning of one resource depends on creation of another from the same configuration.
ref: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on
